# Any way to set a breakpoint in GDB without stopping the target?

Tags: debugging, gdb, embedded, breakpoints

I'm using GDB (through an IDE) to debug an arm cortex microcontroller, and I've encountered an issue where the micro is halted briefly (for 10-20ms) whenever a breakpoint is set or cleared (not *hit*, but *set*, as in the code has not yet reached the breakpoint).  This long of a pause can cause significant problems when driving an electric motor, for example.

The IDE has a debug console which shows that the GDB client is sending a SIGINT to the GDB server whenever I add or remove a breakpoint.  I know that in the command-line client you have to use ctrl+c to interrupt the process to issue any command, but for modern microcontrollers (ARM cortex-m, etc.) it is not necessary to interrupt the processor to insert breakpoints, read memory, and in some cases to trace program execution.  I am wondering if this is something that is being imposed by the GDB interface artificially.

Is there any way to create a new breakpoint without halting the target?

I have tried using "async" mode in GDB, but it informs me that I must halt the program to insert breakpoints.  I have also verified that breakpoints can be set with the underlying debug server (OpenOCD) without halting, so in this case GDB is incorrect.

Any input is appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: The on-chip debug certainly allows it since I can do that in Keil's debugger, but I have no idea whether GDB does.  Have you tried an `hbreak` rather then a plain `break`?  BTW I don't think your question needs justification and if you had not written quite so much for such a straightforward question I might have read it all ;-)  Consider shortening it to just the question.

Comment: @Clifford Thanks for the feedback.  I know sometimes people get answers to the wrong question when they don't understand the reason for it, but in this case I think you are right and the extra information is unnecessary.